# How to use read_csv in dataset with broken pipe "¦" as seprator???

Tags: python, pandas, broken-pipe

I have 10 files datasets 10mb to 8gb, and I am trying to read a dataset txt with size 8gb that I cannot read because of the "¦" (Broken pipe)... Almost all that have size highest than 200mb have this same problem and the smallest files have the "normal" pipe( | ).

The code is:

> ```
> p = 0.001  # % of lines
>
> df = pd.read_csv("protectedSearch_GPRS.txt", sep='¦', 
>                     skiprows= lambda i: i>0 and random.random() > p)
>
>
>      ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the separator 
>      encoded in utf-8 is > 1 char long, and the 'c' engine does not support such 
>      separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
>        after removing the cwd from sys.path.
> ```

So What exactly is it? Is it a bug? How to handle with this problem? I am trying to solve this have 2 days and I really don't know what to do more.

Thank you very much and sorry for any language error.

Comment: are you using a linux machine?

Comment: Hey eagle, I'm using windows 10

Comment: bummer, I have a quick way to change the delimiter but its *nix specific

Comment: That's the unicode "broken bar" character and its not in the ascii character set. Pandas defaults to a C based csv parser, but its single byte only and can't handle that character. The warning tells you pandas is falling back to the slower python implementation. This is mostly harmless. You can avoid the warning by following the instructions in the warning.

Comment: try this in powershell and then load it in with the normal `'|'` delimiter : `(get-content "path:\\protectedSearch_GPRS.txt") -replace '¦','|' | set-content "path:\\protectedSearch_GPRS.txt` just replace `path` with the actual path

Comment: I added engine='python' and it not work... I really don't know what I need to do and I cannot find any resolution on google

Comment: Thank eagle, I will try this

Comment: what's the error when you try `engine='python'`?

Comment: Hey maxymo... It's start loading but never-ending and my computer start  to brake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug. The Pandas C engine only supports single-character splitting. The broken pipe is technically two UTF-8 characters, thus the error the `character is > 1`

For example:

```
len('¦'.encode('utf-8'))
Out[24]: 2
len(','.encode('utf-8'))
Out[25]: 1
```

If you want to suppress the warning, explicitly state which engine you wish to use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
      "protectedSearch_GPRS.txt", 
      sep='¦', 
      skiprows=lambda i: i > 0 and random.random() > p,
      engine='python'
)
```

Using `engine=python` enables matching with multi-string/regex splitting.

Comment: But how can I handle with this problem using this information? Sorry for this question, I'm beginner in IT industry

Comment: just add the additional argument `engine='python` to read_csv.  This will parse with the Python engine instead of C and suppress the warning.

Comment: Hey bro, thank you but It was the first thing I did, but it also not work correctly... It's loading but never-ending and my computer start  to brake

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira if the file is very large, it is likely that your machine is running out of memory to load the file from desk to RAM.  You cannot load a 8GB CSV to a Pandas dataframe if your computer doesn'thave 8GB ram free. Consider using a large VM or Spark cluster in Azure or AWS to process your data. Also, please mark the question as solved as this answer addresses your original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, Montel! I will do that... I am new on stackOverflow yet, sorry